# How to fix UTF8 URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I have links in an html file like

> href="%87%d9%84-%d9%8a%d9%86%d9%81%d8%b9-%d8%a7%d8%ae%d9%84%d9%89-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85%d8%ac-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%85%d9%8a%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%aa%d8%b1%d9%8a%d8%af-%d9%8a%d9%86%d8%a8%d9%87%d9%86%d9%89/index.html"

And I want when the user clicks on this link in the browser, the link will 
be

> RealUtf8Text/index.html

Is There any way to use it using `.htaccess` file ?
If not, how we can do it using a javascript file ?

I don't want to make changes in the files, just add .htaccess or javascript file and the problem is solved.

Comment: that's URL encoding, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your URL does not contain valid UTF-8 data. There is no UTF-8 sequence that begins with the octet `87`.

I'm guessing that your URL is missing a `d9` or `d8` octet. This URL:

> http://localhost/%d9%87%d9%84-%d9%8a%d9%86%d9%81%d8%b9-%d8%a7%d8%ae%d9%84%d9%89-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85%d8%ac-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%85%d9%8a%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%aa%d8%b1%d9%8a%d8%af-%d9%8a%d9%86%d8%a8%d9%87%d9%86%d9%89/index.html

is shown as arabic characters in my browser:

[image: Browser address bar]

How the URL is displayed will of course depend on the browser's support for arabic characters, and is not something that can be affected by JavaScript or .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You use urldecode,

```
urldecode("%87%d9%84-%d9%8a%d9%86%d9%81%d8%b9-%d8%a7%d8%ae%d9%84%d9%89-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85%d8%ac-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%85%d9%8a%d8%aa%d8%a7%d8%aa%d8%b1%d9%8a%d8%af-%d9%8a%d9%86%d8%a8%d9%87%d9%86%d9%89/index.html")
```

see the documentation in
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php.
also make sure you have this on your html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: it is possible using .htaccess or javascript ?

Comment: yes. <script>
function myFunction() {
    var uri = "http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab";
    var res = decodeURIComponent(uri);
   
}
</script>